# what kind of lizard is this

Tags: species-identification, zoology, herpetology

Found on ground by house in residential neighborhood in Fort Pierce FL. looks mature maybe 17". [image]

Answer (score -1):

Nice find. It's a common basilisk or jesus christ lizard, distributed throughout central america, they grow to 27 inches and can run on water, the male is bigger than the female:

https://travel.mongabay.com/colombia/images/colombia_1513.html

[image]

Comment: haha nice downvote. :) i have only 6000 points left. can we go to 6666 plz.